# Outlook Mail Item Property Accessor returning Bad Strings

Tags: vba, outlook, properties

I'm trying to display the values of a number of MailItem Properties using the PropertyAccessor but all I'm getting back is unprintable characters.

I have not found a post with a similar problem.

```
Private Const PRMessageID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E"
Private Const PRConvIndex = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00710102"
Private Const PRSenderEID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C190102"
Private Const PRParentEID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E090102"
Private Const PRStoreEnID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFB0102"
Private Const PR__EntryID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102"
Private Const PRRecordKey = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF90102"
Private Const PRStrRecKey = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFA0102"
Private Const PRSearchKey = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102"

    Public Function AssignMailIDS(oMail As Outlook.MailItem) As String
        AssignMailIDS = oMail.ConversationIndex

    '    oMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PropNameSpace, AssignMailIDS
    '
    '    Debug.Print oMail.PropertyAccessor.getProperty(PropNameSpace)

        oMail.ItemProperties.Add("OriginalConvIdx", olText, True) = AssignMailIDS

        Debug.Print "+++++"
        Debug.Print "-----"
        Debug.Print oMail.UserProperties("OriginalConvIdx")
        Debug.Print "Message ID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRMessageID)
        Debug.Print "Convers ID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRConvIndex)
        Debug.Print "Sender EID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRSenderEID)
        Debug.Print "Parent EID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRParentEID)
        Debug.Print "Store EnID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRStoreEnID)
        Debug.Print "Entry   ID " & GetItemID(oMail, PR__EntryID)
        Debug.Print "Record Key " & GetItemID(oMail, PRRecordKey)
        Debug.Print "StrRec Key " & GetItemID(oMail, PRStrRecKey)
        Debug.Print "Search  ID " & GetItemID(oMail, PRSearchKey)
    End Function

    Public Function GetItemID(oItem As MailItem, sID As String) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        GetItemID = "<Non Existant>"
        GetItemID = oItem.PropertyAccessor.getProperty(sID)
    End Function

        Set oOLapp = OpenOutlook()

        Set oMapi = oOLapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set oSentFolder = oOLapp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(oMapi.DefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Sent Items")

        Set oItems = oSentFolder.Items
        oItems.Sort "[SentOn]", True
        Set oItem = oItems(1) ' Get latest sent item
        Debug.Print "-----"
        Debug.Print "Message ID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRMessageID)
        Debug.Print "Convers ID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRConvIndex)
        Debug.Print "Sender EID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRSenderEID)
        Debug.Print "Parent EID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRParentEID)
        Debug.Print "Store EnID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRStoreEnID)
        Debug.Print "Entry   ID " & GetItemID(oItem, PR__EntryID)
        Debug.Print "Record Key " & GetItemID(oItem, PRRecordKey)
        Debug.Print "StrRec Key " & GetItemID(oItem, PRStrRecKey)
        Debug.Print "Search  ID " & GetItemID(oItem, PRSearchKey)
        sItemConvIdx = oItem.UserProperties("OriginalConvIdx")
```

This results in the following output to the debugger window:

```
+++++
-----
01D34EE4AAEC61381400E9CB4836BA2932216C015C25
Message ID 
Convers ID ????????U+
Sender EID <Non Existant>
Parent EID <Non Existant>
Store EnID <Non Existant>
Entry   ID <Non Existant>
Record Key <Non Existant>
StrRec Key ????????
Search  ID <Non Existant>
-----
Message ID 
Convers ID ???????????
Sender EID   ???????   ???????????????????????????
Parent EID   ???????????????? ?? 
Store EnID   ??????? ?????    ???????? ???????????????????????????????????????????8??T   Walter.ZAMBOTTI@police.wa.gov.au  
Entry   ID   ???????????????? ?? ????????A?? 
Record Key   ????????????????A?? 
StrRec Key ????????
Search  ID ????????
```

I was originally trying to obtain the Message ID but was surprised when that was blank so I tried retrieving other values and haven't found any that work.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: what do you see if you examine `GetItemID(oMail, PRMessageID)` in the `watch window` ?

Comment: i checked ... it is a series of bytes .... does not appear to be unicode  ... possibly encrypted data

Comment: check here https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/ .... it is binary data

Comment: The answer is to wrap the output in PropertyAccessor.BinaryToText method.  The GetProperty method while returning a String apparently returns SPECIAL Strings that requires binary conversion!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
Public Function GetItemID(oItem As MailItem, sID As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetItemID = "<Non Existant>"
    GetItemID = oItem.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToText(oItem.PropertyAccessor.getProperty(sID))
End Function
```

Of course some of the strings returned actually are strings while others are binary requiring conversion.  This means you will need to make the above function accept an optional IsBinary flag so you can select to convert or not.